# Birthday query not working if dob is null

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

I have user model with dob as bellow

```
field :dob, :type => Date
```

I want to find user's whose birthday is today. I tried with

```
    User.collection.aggregate([
    { "$project" => {
        "dob" => {
            "day" => { "$dayOfMonth" => "$dob" },
            "month" => { "$month" => "$dob" }
        }

    }},
    { "$match" => {
        "dob.day" => Time.now.day,
        "dob.month" => Time.now.month
    }}
  ])
```

It is only working if all user has dob. If any one user has dob = null, it is not working.

Getting this error

```
    Moped::Errors::OperationFailure: The operation: #<Moped::Protocol::Command
      @length=249
      @request_id=2
      @response_to=0
      @op_code=2004
      @flags=[:slave_ok]
      @full_collection_name="api_development.$cmd"
      @skip=0
      @limit=-1
      @selector={:aggregate=>"users", :pipeline=>[{"$project"=>{"dob"=>{"day"=>{"$dayOfMonth"=>"$dob"}, "month"=>{"$month"=>"$dob"}}}}, {"$match"=>{"dob"=>{"$ne"=>nil}, "dob.day"=>30, "dob.month"=>10}}]}
      @fields=nil>
    failed with error 16006: "exception: can't convert from BSON type NULL to Date"
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What means "not working"? No results or an error?

Comment: @ChristianStrempfer, I updated question with the error

Answer (score 0):

Probably your aggregation fails because it can't apply the date functions on NULL, therefore you have to remove documents with dob equals NULL.

```
User.collection.aggregate([
    { "$match" => {
        "dob" => { "$ne" => nil }
    }},
    { "$project" => {
        "dob" => {
            "day" => { "$dayOfMonth" => "$dob" },
            "month" => { "$month" => "$dob" }
        }
    }},
    { "$match" => {
        "dob.day" => Time.now.day,
        "dob.month" => Time.now.month
    }}
])
```

Comment: yes, but my original code was working if I have all users with dob,while yours is not working even with that case.
I think $ifNull should work, but may be we are using it incorrectly.

Comment: @Alpesh: Sorry, I can't test it right now. I'll fix it as soon as I can.

Comment: thanks man, I am also working on this, will update if I fix it

Comment: @Alpesh: I'm not sure why `ifNull` doesn't work with nested documents, but I got it working with another `match` step at the beginning.

Comment: No, I haven't fixed this issue yet. I have used mongoid 3 which is very old now. So going to upgrade to mongoid 4. With mongoid4 I will work to fix this issue.